# 'Fix all auto-fixable problems' doesn't fix as many issues as possible vscode-eslint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, vscode-extensions, vscode-eslint

Often times, when I try to run the **, Fix all auto-fixable issues** command on my Javascript files, the app goes into a never-ending loop of moving the tabs/spaces around, but never really getting satisfied:

[image: autof-xable]

My `.eslintrc.js` is as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const prettierOptions = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./.prettierrc', 'utf8'));

module.exports = {
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  extends: ['airbnb', 'prettier', 'prettier/react'],
  plugins: ['prettier', 'redux-saga', 'react', 'jsx-a11y'],
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    jest: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': ['error', prettierOptions],
    'arrow-body-style': [2, 'as-needed'],
    'class-methods-use-this': 0,
    'comma-dangle': [2, 'always-multiline'],
    'import/imports-first': 0,
    'import/newline-after-import': 0,
    'import/no-dynamic-require': 0,
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 0,
    'import/no-named-as-default': 0,
    'import/no-unresolved': 2,
    'import/no-webpack-loader-syntax': 0,
    'import/prefer-default-export': 0,
    indent: [
      2,
      2,
      {
        SwitchCase: 1,
      },
    ],
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0,
    'jsx-a11y/aria-props': 2,
    'jsx-a11y/heading-has-content': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/label-has-for': 2,
    'jsx-a11y/mouse-events-have-key-events': 2,
    'jsx-a11y/role-has-required-aria-props': 2,
    'jsx-a11y/role-supports-aria-props': 2,
    'max-len': 0,
    'newline-per-chained-call': 0,
    'no-confusing-arrow': 0,
    'no-console': 1,
    'no-use-before-define': 0,
    'prefer-template': 2,
    'react/jsx-closing-tag-location': 0,
    'react/forbid-prop-types': 0,
    'react/jsx-first-prop-new-line': [2, 'multiline'],
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': 0,
    'react/jsx-no-target-blank': 0,
    'react/require-default-props': 0,
    'react/require-extension': 0,
    'react/self-closing-comp': 0,
    'react/sort-comp': 0,
    'redux-saga/no-yield-in-race': 2,
    'redux-saga/yield-effects': 2,
    'require-yield': 0,
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      webpack: {
        config: './internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Could anyone help me with resolving this issue?

Answer (score 22):

Try adding following configs to vscode settings.json

```json
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    // For ESLint
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    // For TSLint
    "source.fixAll.tslint": true,
    // For Stylelint
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
  },
```

Comment: This answer worked well for me! I added this with ```"editor.formatOnSave": true,```

Answer (score 11):

**UPD:**

Now you can just choose `vscode-eslint` / `prettier` as your default formatter and it should format file in one pass:

1. `ctrl` + `shift` + `p`
2. Choose `Format document with...`
3. Select `Configure default foramtter`
4. Select your preferred formatter

**OLD:**

This is old issue in [vscode-eslint](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/154) extention due to limitation of vscode formatting API. One possible solution is to fix code via cli:

```
eslint --fix
```

Answer (score 1):

Install extension Toggle Format on Save, 
And press CMD+SHIFT+P type Toggle Format on Save > Enter.

Hope to help.

Answer (score 0):

In my **settings.json** was rule that broke my eslint formatting
(remove it):

```
 "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
```

With this rule, every time after saving,
VS Code will apply eslint rules,
then applies prettier rules,
and as a result,
the formatter's code will look wrong
(like without formatting).

Answer (score -2):

**Simple fix :** In VS Code open `setting.json` file and put `"editor.formatOnSave": true,`.  This will autofix on save.